# Formatting dates in Underscore templates

Tags: php, javascript, date, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a `date` attribute in a Backbone model used in an **underscore template**.
The `date` value is in integer format like **123456432**.

I want to show this integer value in **dd / mm / yyyy** format in an underscore template, like the way I do in PHP.

Here is my underscore template

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">    
    <span class="label label-info"><%- name %> <em> <%= date %> </em>  </span>
</script>
```

Comment: How do You pass the data to the template? Simply call the toJSON method of the model?

Comment: yes i used toJSON method .. is there any other way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Underscore templates let you call function and output text in any way you see fit via `print`. For example, to convert your timestamp to a date, you could use something like this

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-1">    
    <span class="label label-info"><% print(new Date(date*1000)) %></span>
</script>
```

Note that I assume the timestamp comes from PHP, thus in seconds. In Javascript, the timestamps are expected to be in milliseconds, that's why I multiply it by 1000.

If your timestamps come from Javascript, use

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-1">    
    <span class="label label-info"><% print(new Date(date)) %></span>
</script>
```

[Formatting this date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) could be done like this

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-2">    
    <span class="label label-info"><% 
        var d = new Date(date*1000), // or d = new Date(date)
            fragments = [
                d.getDate(),
                d.getMonth() + 1,
                d.getFullYear()
            ]; 
            print(fragments.join('/'));
        %></span>
</script>
```

Or factorize all this into a function call (here on `_.template` but you could store it anywhere)

```js
_.template.formatdate = function (stamp) {
    var d = new Date(stamp*1000), // or d = new Date(date)
        fragments = [
            d.getDate(),
            d.getMonth() + 1,
            d.getFullYear()
        ]; 
    return fragments.join('/');
};
```

```html
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-3">    
    <span class="label label-info"><%= _.template.formatdate(date) %></span>
</script>
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/Dyzm8/

Comment: thanks bro, it help me alot but i still got random time rather them current time .. .
When i first create  event i store the date in my database  as `date = new Date().getTime()`,integer format, and i retrieve by using ur first method.unluckily it give wrong time everytime ...

Comment: If the date timestamp comes from Javascript, it already is in milliseconds and you should not multiply it by 1000. Use `print(new Date(date))` for example

Comment: why push logic down to templates?

Comment: @Blacksonic I wouldn't consider date formatting being app logic but to each his own

Comment: Great explanation, my friend

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

When passing the result of the toJSON method, extend the object with another field:

```
var fields = this.model.toJSON();
fields.formattedDate = '29/11/1973';
this.template(fields);
```

The other way is to have a look at [Backbone Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/), which has [helper methods](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#viewtemplatehelpers) for such cases (and solves many other repetitive tasks).

A simple PHP date function port in Javascript can be found [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/date/).